# Testing Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a sample of 40 data, that shows the average of time a person waits in a gas station line.

Descriptive statistics of this sample are as follow:
N= 40, mean= 115sec, std.dev.=11sec, min=90sec, max=147sec.

I decided to test the following hypothesis:
H0: waiting time = 115sec
H1: waiting time is not 115sec

Please tell me how I can test my hypothesis?

Comment: You got mean same as needed, no test

Comment: It seems as a simple linear regression with one variable. So the mean is what you're looking for as @HemantRupani sad before. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAgYLRy7e20

Comment: It sounds like you might have formulated your hypothesis upon looking at the data. Trying to test it against the same data would be circular--that is, illogical. It would be somewhat the same as flipping a coin, seeing that it lies heads up, turning to a friend, and saying "How much would you like to bet that it's heads?"

Answer (score 0):

You can test that hypothesis with the standard t-test. Simply compute:

$$
\frac{t_0 - t_1}{se(t_0)} 
$$

Where $t_1$ is the value under the null (that value you think $t$ should have). And $t_0$ is the value of $t$ estimated from your data (the sample mean of 115). $se(t_0)$ is the sample standard deviation. Under very general asumptions, this statistic follows a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

The point made in the comments is that since $t_0 = 115$, testing $H_0: t_0 = 115$ can never be rejected. It is often much more interesting to compute the confidence interval, that way you can say: "I am $1- \alpha\%$ sure that (the true but unknown parameter) $t_0$ falls within this interval". [This wiki has a neat discussion of CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)